# Obtain expression inside one parenthesis inside double parenthesis in python

Tags: python, string, parentheses

Suppose there is the following code

```
s= 'hello {world {123} }'  
print s[s.find("{")+1:s.find("}")]
```

it gives me

```
"world {123"
```

What should I do to obtain

```
world {123}
```

?

Comment: Perhaps doing `print(s[s.find("{")+1:s.find(" }")])` ?

Comment: Use .rfind("}") to find the closing brace - the reverse search will find the last occurrence, rather than the first.

Comment: Thank you both of you! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

When slicing the `end` argument is exclusive, so you will need to add 1 to the result of `find`:

```
print s[s.find("{") + 1: s.find("}") + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never used this find method before, but I messed around a little bit and I've found if you use:

```
print s[s.find("{")+1:s.find("}")+1]
```

it will return the results you're looking for.
Thanks for helping me learn something new.